# Upload file on server using html5 page and file input type

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, generic-handler

I have a html5 page and need to upload a image file on some server path and want to show the uploaded file back on the page.
I have used jquery to read the file path and using the ajax tried to call a handler. But we are not able to read the full file path in jquery.

If used the  tag and put the file input type in it and on its post call the handler then we are able to read the file path using context.Request.Files["ID"] and save but not able to show the uploaded file on html page.

Can any body please suggest how to uplaod the file using html File input type

Thanks 
supriya

Answer (score -1):

Generally you can't access or post files using JavaScript (and thus neither with jQuery or AJAX). There are ways around this, but for your first attempt it would be much easier just to use simple form with an `<input type="file" ...>` and without any JavaScript.

You didn't mention what you are using server-side (I'm guessing C#/ASP/.NET which I'm only slightly familiar with), but basically all you normally get there is the pure data from the image file (no file name or file path) and you have to write that data to a file yourself (or do something else with it, such as write it to a database).

However some web frameworks will write the file for you and provide you with a path to created the file instead, but I don't know if you are using something like that.

Then you'll need to copy the created file somewhere into public directory of your web server (or write it directly there, if you are creating the file yourself) so you can refer to it in the `img` element of your HTML file that displays the image. Alternatively you can use a separate server-side script, that reads the image file and returns the data with the correct MIME-type.